# Launch logme.py on boot

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04

I have been trying to make a program launch on starting my system.
here is my problem..

ulogme [(https://github.com/karpathy/ulogme)](https://github.com/karpathy/ulogme) is a personal time tracker.
But after installation it needs to launched every time by running

**$ python ulogme_serve.py**

I want this script to run automatically on startup.

Solution by  Atto Allas  works well.

I am facing a new problem now,
I keep getting the following error

*

```
*    Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>  
    main()  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 566, in main  
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages  
    user_site = getusersitepackages()  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages  
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase  
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 595, in get_config_var  
    return get_config_vars().get(name)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 538, in get_config_vars  
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 410, in _init_posix  
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>  
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *  
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'**
```

Any suggestion and help are welcome
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You may want to look at this Ask Ubuntu answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up#816

Answer (score 2):

**If you want it to run at login**

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Step 1: In the dashboard, search for 'startup applications'

Step 2: In the preferences screen that comes up, click 'add'

Step 3: Choose a name (for example, 'Ulogme Tracker'), a command to run (`python ulogme_serve.py`) and a comment ('Personal time tracker')

Step 4: Finally, click 'add'.

This should make it so that **any time you log in**, it will start ulogme_serve.py.

**If you want it to run at system startup**

> https://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/07/adding-a-startup-script-to-be-run-at-bootup/

Step 1: Create a shell script called ulogme_startup.sh by typing `sudo nano /etc/init.d/ulogme_startup.sh` in terminal

Step 2: In the editor, type `python ulogme_serve.py`

Step 3: Hit 'ctrl+x' then 'y' and then hit 'enter'

Step 4: Back at the terminal, type `sudo update-rc.d ulogme_startup.sh defaults`

Step 5: Finally type `sudo chmod +x ulogme_startup.sh`

This should now run **at system startup**.

I hope this helps!

N.B. This will only work if ulogme_serve.py is on your path, if it isn't, change all instances of `ulogme_serve.py` to its absolute filepath. For example, if it was in a folder called 'ulogme' in your home folder, you would replace `ulogme_serve.py` with `/home/<your username>/ulogme/ulogme_serve.py`.

Comment: @PradeepBV If you found it useful, consider marking my answer as correct so others with a similar goal may find it.